# Docker: give a random port mapping only to certain ports

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker 1.9.1's remote API to create a container.

One thing I'm trying to accomplish is that among all the exposed ports of an image, I only want to expose a few of them (or in other words give them host port mapping), at the same time I don't want to manage the host ports to use but want Docker to pick up random and available ones.

For example, an image has port 80, 443, 22 exposed, what I want is something like this in a Docker run flavor (I know this is not possible through cmd line though)

`docker run -p {a random available port}:80 image`

Can I achieve something like this through remote API? Right now I can only set `PublishAllPorts = true` but that publish all ports and waste too many host ports.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just do `docker run -p 80 image`.

Comment: docker rest api for starting container allows you to define port bindings. For random mapping to host port use "PortBindings": { "80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "" }] }

Comment: @Shibashis, this works! The other property ExposedPorts was confusing here. Thanks, you wanna move this to an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: And as @oliver has mentioned it is possible using cmd line as well

Comment: Yup, I didn't try the cmd out earlier but it's great to learn that. Thanks @OliverCharlesworth as well!

Comment: No problem!  (As far as I can see, it's not actually documented anywhere.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker rest api for starting container allows you to define port bindings. For random mapping to host port use "PortBindings": { "80/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "" }] }

Comment: This is not a published interface.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerCreate

Does not seem to work with Docker 20.